# Is it possible to invoke a non runnable?

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to somehow invoke an instance like this? I know invokeLater requires a runnable in which I could just pass a new instance in the method, but I need to be able to access the instance once it's been invoked.

```
public class Main {

  // Create a new instance of the applet frame
  private static final AppletFrame APPLET_FRAME = new AppletFrame();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Somehow invoke that applet frame without creating a new one here 
      so we can access it later on like below.
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(APPLET_FRAME);
      // Then if this is possible I can access the invoked instance still.
      // APPLET_FRAME.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: "_but I need to be able to access the instance once it's been invoked_" - please explain why your current approach doesn't work - what can't `AppletFrame implements Runnable`? Further, what are you trying to do with the `AppletFrame` after passing it to `invokeLater`? Given you have no guarantees whatsoever that it is been invoked, as that happens **later**, there would seem to be no difference than calling `doSomething` _before_ passing the reference?

Comment: I'm working with a GUI in which I need to add and remove things from the applet frame after it's invoked therfore I need to access the instance of applet frame that is define in the code above, although invokeLater only accepts a "Runnable" as a parameter so the problem is trying to invoke the applet frame but still have access to the instance if that makes sense?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I don't understand. Firstly, the reason you use `invokeLater` is because it is _illegal_ to access Swing elements from a thread that isn't the EDT - you calling a method on `AppletFrame` that in any changes the GUI from the main thread will violate Swing's concurrency requirements. As to the rest, I am confused - you have `AppletFrame APPLET_FRAME`, that `implements Runnable` so you pass that to `invokeLater`. You then still have a reference to _that instance_ in the `APPLET_FRAME` variable.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's why I'm trying to do this. I'm trying to use `invokeLater` now since it's the proper way and everything is correct although there is 3 methods I use to access swing elements in one of my invokes that I have to do, but I'm not sure where else to do them because they have to execute in a specific order. The applet frame doesn't implement runnable at all.

Comment: The *what* should be invoked later? invokeLater expects a Runnable, because it invoked the runnable, I.e. calls its run() method. Which method of AppletFrame should be invoked later?

Comment: APPLET_FRAME is still accesible by its name or getWindows() returns list of all TopLevelContainers, visibility of this/those Object(s) must be inside invokeLater